# Where to find list of AWS Region IDs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-regions

I am looking at these two comment replies:

- [Terraform ELB access_log S3 access Permissions Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47087131/174777)
- [Assign ELB Account to S3 Bucket Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72148185/174777)

Which include the following list:

```
Region, ELB Account Principal ID
us-east-1, 127311923021
us-east-2, 033677994240
us-west-1, 027434742980
us-west-2, 797873946194
ca-central-1, 985666609251
eu-west-1, 156460612806
eu-central-1, 054676820928
eu-west-2, 652711504416
ap-northeast-1, 582318560864
ap-northeast-2, 600734575887
ap-southeast-1, 114774131450
ap-southeast-2, 783225319266
ap-south-1, 718504428378
sa-east-1, 507241528517
us-gov-west-1*, 048591011584
cn-north-1*, 638102146993
```

What I want to know is where are these IDs obtained from? For example, where can I go to look up 027434742980 myself? I've tried searching the AWS docs and CLI docs. Also, is there a way I can dynamically reference this ID in my CloudFormation template? That way I don't have to deal with hard-coded values.

Answer (score 2):

Found it. In [Enable access logs for your Application Load Balancer - Elastic Load Balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/enable-access-logging.html#attach-bucket-policy), I had to expand the "Regions available before August 2022" widget.